# Spark running in local machine instead of standalone cluster

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've created a spark cluster on ec2, after that, I installed Jupyter on the master node and started jupyter, after that I  created sparkcontext using

```
findspark.init(spark_home='/home/ubuntu/spark')
import pyspark
from functools import partial
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")
```

when I am trying to run any job, spark is only utilizing cores of the master machine, all the slaves are running and connected to master, but I am still not able to use the cores of any of the slave machines, anybody please help.

Comment: You need to set master url to `spark://...`

Comment: While creating the sparkcontext?

Comment: yes, it is at least necessary

Comment: nice, I post this as an answer for a more wide help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the master url to `spark://...` when creating your `SparkContext`